# Characterization of harmonic functions as a gravitational potential

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-functions

It is stated in a book I'm reading that every harmonic function can be written as a gravitational potential. The book refers to this fact only in passing and doesn't provide a precise statement.

I'd like to know if this theorem has a name and who first proved it. I'd also like a reference giving a statement and proof of this fact, preferably a book with modern notations and standards of precision (for math, not physics).

Comment: This is Newtonian physics?

Comment: I presume so, but as I said, the book only mentioned the fact in passing, so I'm asking the question in part to try to fill in the missing information.

Comment: What is the title of the book? Where is the passage?

Comment: Ok so the $\nabla f$ is gravity, now show is $\nabla^2 f=0$

Comment: @marshalcraft Well no, it's the converse that's needed.

Comment: Poisson's equation models the potential generated by a mass density $\rho$: $\nabla^2\Phi= 4\pi G \rho$

Comment: @dantopa I don't think it's helpful, but this is in Postnikov's *Lectures in Geometry*, Volume 2. It says, "As will be shown in the course in mathematical-physics equations, *any harmonic function is the potential of the gravitational field of some mass.*" The reason this isn't helpful to me is because the reference he makes to a course is most likely to some course math students at Moscow State University take later on, not to a specific book.

Comment: Maybe something you can show has zero divergence?

Comment: If you have a harmonic function in a disk, you can recover it by integrating a distribution on the boundary. You could interpret the boundary distribution as a mass distribution and the harmonic function as the gravitational potential. (This is gravitation in a vacuum - within a mass distribution, the distribution is proportional to the Laplacian of the potential.)

Comment: @Neal Do you have a reference for this?